# After Update Advanced Gutenberg Plugin - advgb/container site does not support block

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I update Advanced Gutenberg plugin. I had create page which use container block. 
After updating the plugin, I can not edit the page because the site does not support block "advgb/container".

How resolve ?

Comment: You should probably ask the plugin author for support as third party plugins and support issues are considered off-topic here on WPSE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been partially resolved. The plug-in provider said that you need to install the older version of the "advanced-gutenberg-v1.10.12" plugin, edit the blocks and later update the plugin